# Is there a Linux equivalent for Windows "InterLockedCompareExchange" API?

Tags: linux, multithreading, api, posix

Is there any posix/thread related API that could help to make "a value change operation" thread-safe, without locking several statements?

Is there a posix API for Linux to do this?

Comment: Like a lot of folks, I get to see a lot of poor questions, broad questions, and questions asking for tutorials. I'm not sure this question is one of them. I think it may be poorly researched or poorly worded at the moment, but I'm not sure its close worthy for the stated reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GCC has [atomic built-ins](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.3/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html#Atomic-Builtins), `__sync_val_compare_and_swap` should be equivalent of `InterLockedCompareExchange`
If you use C++ 11, you can use `std::atomic_compare_exchange_*` in [atomic operations library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_compare_exchange) as needed.